# R-related: adding vector to data frame; incongruent number of obs

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I want to add a vector from an existing data.frame to another data.frame. The number of rows are not identical. Both data.frames hold data for some 32 countries. Each of which is (following tidy data principle) subdivided into years (1991-2015), so there's 24 rows for each country; there are missing values in both dfs, however whereas in the first df this is represented in the table itself, in the second df no NAs are included. Hence, e.g., Canada as a country only consists of 20 rows, since there's no data available for 2010-2015.

I would assume one could add the necessary NA information to the second df via loops but dont quite know how to do this.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `merge` using the common variables in both data.frames. If you use `all.x = T`, and the `x` dataframe is the longer with the `NA`s, the `merge` won't omit rows that there's no match for in the second data frame.